# Celery throwing IOError when retrying a task

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm intermittently (about 20% of the time) getting an IOError exception from Celery when I attempt to retry a failed task.

Here is my task:

```
@task
def update_data(pk_id):
     try:
        pk = PK.objects.get(pk=pk_id)
        results = pk.get_update()
        return results
    except urllib2.HTTPError, exc:
        print "Let's retry in a few minutes."
        update_data.retry(exc=exc, countdown=600)
```

The exception:

```
[2011-10-07 11:35:53,594: ERROR/MainProcess] Task report.tasks.update_data[1babd4e3-45eb-4fa3-a497-68b67bb4a6df] raised exception: IOError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prj/prj_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 36, in trace
    return cls(states.SUCCESS, retval=fun(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/prj/prj_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/app/task/__init__.py", line 232, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/prj/prj_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/app/__init__.py", line 172, in run
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/prj/prj/report/tasks.py", line 109, in update_data
    update_data.retry(exc=exc, countdown=600)
  File "/home/prj/prj_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/app/task/__init__.py", line 520, in retry
    self.name, options["task_id"], args, kwargs))
HTTPError
```

RabbitMQ Logs

```
=INFO REPORT==== 7-Oct-2011::15:35:43 ===
closing TCP connection <0.4294.17> from 10.254.122.225:59704

=WARNING REPORT==== 7-Oct-2011::15:35:43 ===
exception on TCP connection <0.4330.17> from 10.254.122.225:59715
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Oct-2011::15:35:43 ===
closing TCP connection <0.4330.17> from 10.254.122.225:59715

=WARNING REPORT==== 7-Oct-2011::15:35:49 ===
exception on TCP connection <0.4313.17> from 10.254.122.225:59709
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Oct-2011::15:35:49 ===
closing TCP connection <0.4313.17> from 10.254.122.225:59709

=WARNING REPORT==== 7-Oct-2011::15:35:49 ===
exception on TCP connection <0.4350.17> from 10.254.122.225:59720
connection_closed_abruptly

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Oct-2011::15:35:49 ===
closing TCP connection <0.4350.17> from 10.254.122.225:59720

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Oct-2011::15:36:22 ===
accepted TCP connection on [::]:5672 from 10.255.199.63:50526

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Oct-2011::15:36:22 ===
starting TCP connection <0.4501.17> from 10.255.199.63:50526
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like it's raising `HTTPError`, not `IOError`?

Comment: @asksol I'm having the same issue, It's an HTTP Error, however the email notifications celery sends are: "Task some_task with id 7e1d88a9-ef58-4b30-b523-c879d9e90402 raised exception:
'IOError()'"

Answer (score 0):

> May be save each task in database and retry them if no result is
>   received for some time? Or may be dispatcher have it's own persistent
>   storage? What about then if worker thread crash receiving the task or
>   while executing it?

[Retry Lost or Failed Tasks (Celery, Django and RabbitMQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336645/retry-lost-or-failed-tasks-celery-django-and-rabbitmq/5339543#5339543)

Answer (score 0):

[max_retries](http://ask.github.com/celery/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=retry#celery.app.task.BaseTask.retry) in celery is per default 3, so if the same task fails 3 times in a row (i.e. 20% of the time), retry will rethrow the exception.